# In an election the number of candidates is one more than ...

Tags: combinatorics

In an election, the number of candidates is one more than the number of members to be elected. A voter can cast any number of votes but not more than the candidates to be elected. If a voter can cast his vote in 30 ways, then the number of the candidates is?

Comment: And can the voter cast multiple votes for one candidate?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question has been answered: please accept that answer if it satisfies you (the checkmark). You may also upvote it (the up arrow). If you ask more questions you should know that the best ones show not only the problem but what you've done yourself to try to solve it. Ones like this are often downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of candidates.

---

Implicit assumption: you cannot give more than one vote to each candidate.

Without the restriction "you cannot cast more votes than the number of candidates to be elected", the number of ways to vote would be $2^n$: For each candidate you have a binary choice, vote for him or not.

With the restriction, you're not allowed to vote for all of them, so one less possibility; there remains $2^n-1$ possible ways of voting.

The equation $2^n-1=30$ has no integer solution, so **the way it is phrased, the problem has no solution**.

However, **if you had the constraint that you have to cast at least one vote** [A], the "support no-one" option is lost, you have one less way to vote and the equation becomes $2^n-2=30$. Now it has one and only one solution, **$n=5$**.

With the precision [A], we can solve the problem. **There are $5$ candidates and $4$ seats**.

---

Implicit assumption: you can give more than one vote to the same candidate.
That's another job...

Comment: It could also be that the voter can cast multiple votes for the same candidate, which might give a different solution.

Comment: I think someone who casts no votes is not considered a voter, which gets you to the $n=5$ solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan : yes, I suppose this is the implicit claim in the problem's formulation, but I prefer to make it clear. CameronBuie : another implicit claim, and one that I didn't consider... I'll look into it